# Firefox 22.0 vertical padding issue

Tags: css, firefox, padding

I'm having an issue in Firefox only (22.0) when using padding on a block element, the bottom padding is different of the top padding while the padding for both is the same in css.

CSS where #navigation is the element container:

```
nav#navigation {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

nav#navigation ul.menu {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#navigation a.my-element {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ff8833;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav#navigation a.my-element span {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: url("assets/img/icon-plus.png") no-repeat left center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="clearfix" role="navigation">

    <ul class="sf-menu menu">
        <li><a href="#">list element</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list element</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list element</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="my-element"><span>Some Text</span></a>

</nav>
```

Here is a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/wzypkwu2l/

Any fix for that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the html and other related css? There's not enough info here to give a solid answer

Comment: Your problem is presented out of context.  Your link is part of a menu layout and the cause of the top/bottom padding variation may have to do with other CSS rules in the original style sheet.  There may be a 1-2 pixel difference in the rendering of the top/bottom padding depending on the font design.  Please provide more information.